# PHP - call to a variable static method using the scope resolution operator

Tags: php, scope-resolution

I would like to call to a static method in such a way that class name and method name are variables.

Example:

```
class QQQ {
   public function www($x) {
      echo $x;
   }
}

$q = 'QQQ';
$w = 'www';

$q::$w(7); // this is what I am trying to do but it throws an error.
```

Thoughts?

Comment: you have not defined $x, that's why the error

Comment: I put something instead of $x, same error.

Comment: Your method is **not static**!

Comment: what kind of error it throws?

Comment: function name must be a string...

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change

```
public function www($x) {
```

to

```
public static function www($x) {
```

Because, you are calling it by scope resolution operator `::` so, it should be static **OR** you should change the way you are calling it

```
$test = new $q;

$test->$w(5);
```

Should work, depending on what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: Can you please explain why?
Directly calling QQQ::foo(7) does the work. But calling it $q::$w(7) says function name must be a string